# How can I publish a global path exactly once?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using move_base package from navigation stack in ROS. For the parameters, I have selected o use grid_path due to my robot's motion limitations. Everything works as expected but now, whenever I send a goal (2d nav goal on rviz), move_base constructs a full path from the beginning till the goal point and the topic is called `/move_base/GlobalPlanner/plan` . The problem is that the topic continuously spams with the same path message until robot gets to the destination. How can I make to publish a single message to the topic and not spam?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/307698/how-can-i-publish-a-global-path-exactly-once?/) by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 361 on 2018-11-06

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mewbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/34476/mewbot/) on 2018-11-06**:
try using a service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well you could use a service, that way it behaves in a request/response kind of way.
Check this service `nav_msgs/GetPlan` from here http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/srv/GetPlan.html

You'll send:

```
geometry_msgs/PoseStamped start

geometry_msgs/PoseStamped goal

float32 tolerance
```

and you'll get a:

```
nav_msgs/Path plan
```

If you need to learn more about services the wiki is your friend http://wiki.ros.org/Services

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2018-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemartin](https://answers.ros.org/users/37019/stevemartin/) on 2018-11-06**:
Okay, I got it, thanks :)